How to remove old add-on interfaces?

I have rebusFarm interface permanently stuck on my render tab even tho the addon's been deactivated and it's source .zip file has been deleted and it's apps uninstalled. the addon doesn't even sho up in add-on settings. How do I get rid of this for good?

Apparently you need to follow the instructions on Rebus Farm site. It shouldn't be too complicated.
If you don't find the icon in you PC (or MAC I guess), simply write "Rebus" on the search bar and the app should appear so you can proceed with the guidelines by Rebus.
Hope this helps.
Rebus Farm, how to uninstall and reinstall
